# Security in Webservice without login credentials

Tags: android, web-services, security, token, sts-securitytokenservice

I'm development a SOAP web service version 1.1 in Java.

I have the following situation:

1. there's a secured channel with ssh;
2. customers don't have login credentials (they don't have username and password);
3. when a customer opens an account is generated a session token;
4. when a customer make requests is validated by their session token;
5. when a customer account is open only him or employee is allowed to close the account (session timeout can't exist);

what is the best way to implement security in this situation? should i generate the session tokens or there is already apis/frameworks to do that job? Does STS (Security Token Service) able to do it without requirements of login credentials?

the purpose of that is to invoke the web service in android application.